# API routing 404 if optional parameter missed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this routing set up in my WebApiConfig

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    }
```

and these methods inside /Api/ProductController.cs

```
    public object GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var productRepo = new ProductRepository(db);
        var product = productRepo.GetItem(id);
        return product.ToAnonymousType();
    }

    public object GetTest()
    {
        var productRepo = new ProductRepository(this.db);
        var product = productRepo.GetItem(10000);
        return product.ToAnonymousType();
    }
```

I can request /api/product/getproduct/10000 and get JSON back.

If I request /api/product/gettest I get a 404

If I change gettest to

```
public object GetTest(int id)
```

and request /api/product/gettest/10000 I get JSON.

I have no idea why that 404 is happening. I have other controllers (for non-api requests) that are handling requests as normal. I'm new to MVC after some years of webforms, and this has me stumped. For reference, here's my RouteConfig

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

and my Application_Start

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the ordering of your routes.

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

is called before

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

and your RegisterRoutes method contains a default (and very generic) route

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

this generic (default) rule will match your url pattern of

```
api/product/gettest
```

before your WebAPI route will get a chance to match it.

You can either get rid of that super generic route if not needed (and use more specific routes), or simply move the call to

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

to come before the call to

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

in your Global.asax.

I built a sample with all of the info you gave, and moving that call worked just fine.
I hope this helps.